# How can I restore node modules for multiple platforms?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

My Node application needs to be deployed on Windows and Linux. The main deployment package is built on a Linux CI server.

When this package is deployed to Windows, it crashes immediately due to missing native bindings, such as those for sqlite. Only the bindings for the build platform (Linux) are restored.

With a deadline approaching, we just set up a Windows build configuration which outputs a Windows specific package that contains the appropriate bindings, and we choose the appropriate artifact to bundle in the installer.

This works but feels fragile, as we would need to keep the Node versions in sync between the two otherwise unrelated environments. I would like to be able to do this with a single build configuration.

I couldn't find any guidance on how this is done. I'm imagining a command-line option like `--platform=windows` to `npm ci`, or a modification to `package.json` but I couldn't find any information about this. Presumably this is a reasonably rare requirement, and perhaps there is no tooling around this, which would be a shame.

Another requirement is that the application must be installed without an internet connection. We cannot run `npm ci` or `npm install` when we install it as some of our clients do not permit their servers to access the public internet.

Comment: Why are you building on a separate machine? Node was designed with the assumption that you build on the machine you are installing on

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know that. But in my situation this is not possible as the application must be installed 100% offline in an air-gapped environment. Perhaps it's possible to download a subsection of NPM and ship it with the app, like you can do with RPM?

Comment: It depends on the project and packages your using, if they contain binaries, then you need to npm install. Have you thought about using docker?

Comment: *Another requirement is that the application must be installed without an internet connection.* is tricky as you should aim to deploy from git, not some USB stick shenanigans

Comment: You can't use Docker on Windows 2012, which is one of the main platforms the software is used on. Docker would be an excellent choice otherwise, and I expect that this is how we will distribute the software one day (once corporate IT teams are used to it).

Comment: That's interesting, we don't deploy the app via Git anyway in our Linux SaaS environment; we build the bundle on the CI server and then deploy it to the production servers. It feels safer to me - what happens if NPM is down for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirements it sounds like building a package on each required platform would be the safest bet, with the least number moving parts to go wrong.

As the comments have suggested most projects rely on an `npm install` on the required platform so you are stepping into not that common territory.

> This works but feels fragile, as we would need to keep the Node versions in sync between the two otherwise unrelated environments. I would like to be able to do this with a single build configuration.

Node uses `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` ([displayed on the releases page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)) to track ABI compatibility for native modules. This only changes with a new major Node release number.

The CI builds would need to create app packages for each major version of Node you run on each platform. Keeping the Node.js major versions in sync for the application a good thing in any case. Running Node `N` and `N-1` builds until that can be achieved is good cover and probably the best option with the air gap requirements.

#### NPM Cache

If the air gapped clients are largely on common networks, an NPM cache/proxy ([nexus](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3)/[verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio)) may be of use. The NPM cache will need a process to snapshot the repo after a production `npm install` on all required platforms, to be pushed out to your endpoints. Unfortunately binary modules are often distributed out of band from NPM so won't be stored in regular NPM caches. Each client instance will need a complete build environment to build any native modules from source which can sometime present it's own difficulties on Windows platforms.

#### Alternatives

Node.js is not a great platform for distributing packaged applications to many diverse clients, especially if you need to distribute Node itself.  Any language with an external VM requirement presents difficulties. Nodes package management choices and reliance on native modules exacerbate this.

I've given up in the past and converted clients (albeit thin) to Go, as it lends itself to cross platform distribution a lot better by removing the external runtime requirement and having less variables.

Comment: Ah, the ABI compatibility note is very handy, and something I did not know. This is how I can track if the given package will execute on the target machine - I can publish it as a build parameter and if they don't match up I can fail the build. I can do the same with Node versions as well.

Comment: Also, I agree with your final point about Node not being the best choice if you're not able to use something like Docker, but there were good technical reasons for choosing it despite this. I look forward to the day where we can drop support for the Windows installer.